# Combinatorics/counting with an alphabet of 4 characters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I'm trying to finish up a counting problem that goes like this: There's an alphabet of 'a,b,c,d', and each letter can be put in 4 spots. From this alphabet,

a) How many strings can be made by using only 1 'a'? (Other letters can be used more than once)

b) How many strings can be made with 2 'a's?

c) How many strings can be made with no repetitions?

d) How many strings can be made with NO MORE THAN 3 of the same letter?

For a), I see that there must be a character 'a' and it can go in any of the 4 spaces that I have available. From there, I can allocate any number of the remaining 3 letters into the remaining 3 spaces. I see this as a permutation with repetitions, so I model my final expression as $4*3^3=108$.

For b), I take a similar approach. There are 2 'a's, so there are 4 spaces in which the first can be placed and 3 in which the 2nd can be placed. From there, there are 2 spaces in which 3 different letters can be placed, so I model my expression as $4*3*3^2=108$.

For c) there are no repetitions so each letter must be used once. This is a simple permutation without repetition where I have 4 letters and 4 spaces, resulting in $4!=24$.

Finally, for d), I am most uncertain. In this case, since there can be at most 3 of the same letter (meaning there can be 3, 2, or 1 of a certain letter), then I should find each individual number of permutations for each. So if there are 3 of the same letter, there is 4 possible spaces for the first, 3 for the second, 2 for the third, and the last space is occupied by one of the 3 unused letters. If there are 2 of the same letter, I have the same case as in b). If there is 1 of the same letter, I have the same case as in a). I won't calculate 0 because if I had 0 of one letter, another would have to have at least 2 of the same. So my final expression is $(4*3*2*3)+108+108=288$.

I think I am approaching this problem incorrectly, so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It’s worth noting that since the number of possible strings with repetition is $4^4 = 256$, your answer for part **d** can be ruled out straight away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answers to a) and c) are correct.

In b), the two a's are indistinguishable, so you must divide by 2: $$\frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 3^2}{2}=54.$$

You are on the right track for d).  So as not to give you all the answers, I'll answer the question of counting words in which a single letter appears AT LEAST 3 times.

First of all, there are clearly 4 ways in which a single letter appears all four times.
Now let's assume the letter **a** appears exactly 3 times.  Here you made the same mistake as in part b).  These three **a**'s are indistinguishable, so we have to divide by the number of ways in which they can rearranged, so the total number of ways to place the **a**'s is $$\frac{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}.$$  Just as you said, there are 3 remaining letters, so the total words with exactly 3 **a**'s is $$\frac{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} \cdot 3.$$  Now, the same argument works for **b**, **c** and **d**.  Thus, overall, we have $$4 + 4 \cdot \frac{4\cdot 3 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1} \cdot 3 = 52.$$

Comment: You seem to have calculated the number of strings with *at least* three of the same letter.

Comment: @雨が好きな人  Woops!  I'll edit my answer.  (The OP should use my answer with your first comment to get the correct answer!)

Comment: Ah I see. After completing the calculation, I now get 180 for d). Also, according to the math for a), there seems to be a typo. I calculate it as 54. Let me know if I'm missing something!

Comment: @bpryan Yep, thanks.